# What adjustments to the stove gas line so the dw will fit with the cabinets + countertop?

Tags: dishwasher, natural-gas, stove, connectors

The stove gas line is located where my dishwasher needs to go. The dw has a depth of 25in w the door and 24in wide. The base cabinet depth is 24in. **What adjustments to the gas line are recommended so the dw will fit property with the cabinets + quartz countertop** which will be delivered next week. The attached image shows where the gas line currently is and where the dw will go as well as the planned cabinet/counter setup.[image]

Comment: and what is the depth of you counter top ?

Comment: That is a good statement but what is the question?

Comment: Also, please indicate where electrical outlet, (hot) water supply and drain hookup for dishwasher will be.

Comment: @Armand Sink is to the right of the refrigerator and left (around corner) of the dishwasher. Blind cabinet in between, so should be easy to run hot water and drain from left side of the dishwasher to the sink cabinet. Electrical could be anywhere, though my recommendation would be hardwire to a box placed at the bottom of the blind cabinet, immediately to the left of the rear of the dishwasher.

Comment: The gas line needs to be moved to behind the new range location. Both so the DW will fit properly and so that the shut off for the gas is behind the range and not in some obscure, hard to find location. What about an electric outlet for the range ? Most newer units will need that as well for the igniter. What about countertop electrical outlets ? It seems you need an electrician and a plumber (or a good friend who knows both well) before you put in your new cabinets and countertops.

Answer (score 2):

You typically get a small area, primarily at the bottom of the back of the dishwasher, for utility connections, including pass-through to other appliances. It will vary somewhat by dishwasher manufacturer, but [see this link from Whirlpool via Home Depot](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/de/de2e8de4-f01a-43a9-b204-3757c4d4831b.pdf) for an example installation diagram.

In ordinary cabinets (e.g., where you don't have a dishwasher, range or similar floor-to-counter appliance), you have the entire toe-kick area to work with, normally 4" tall. But appliances need a lot of that space. In the case of dishwashers, the bottom space is used for pumps, motors, etc. so that space above it can be used for, you guessed it, dirty dishes.

So the gas line has to move. How hard that will be depends on where it comes from and what kind of access you have. The logical thing to do is to either move it behind the range or to keep it where it is along the wall but have it come up of the wall near the very bottom.

I highly recommend getting a licensed gas plumber to do that work. With electrical it is usually quite obvious whether something is connected properly or not. With water, small leaks are not exactly a good thing, but not generally immediate cause for alarm. With gas, the consequences of a leak can be deadly. And with everything else going on in a renovated kitchen, a problem may not be noticed right away. So get someone to do that who really knows what they're doing, and make sure all connections are thoroughly tested for leaks.